# how to make two widgets centered inside a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-row

I have a custom table and in its rows there is such a widget row (row in row C: ) and I can't figure out how to make them centered, and not as in the screenshot :C

[image]

These properties don't help :C

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

```
Expanded(
  child: Row(
    children: [
       Text(
         item.versionStatus == MockVersionStatus.complete ? 'ready' :  'load',
         style: TextStyleBook.paragraphP2,
       ),
       if (item.versionStatus != MockVersionStatus.complete)
          const SizedBox(width: 10,),
       if (item.versionStatus != MockVersionStatus.complete)
            const ThreeDotsAnimation(),
     ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Can you check out Align Class
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

Comment: Post the entire widget. Provide an image of the current results and an image of the expected results if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get what you mean by centering it.

If you mean horizontally they are not centered, you can check using the inspector, the space they cover. But they seems centered to me :P

Not related to the question but you dont need the same if statement twice, you can use it like this:

```dart
if (item.versionStatus != MockVersionStatus.complete)
    ...[
      const SizedBox(width: 10),
      const ThreeDotsAnimation(),
    ];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking here. why are those properties not working for you, Are you using them properly?

Check [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) to see if it helps. Notice you can change how you split the vertical space in the **Column**, and the horizontal space in the **Row**

Take a look at this example:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("This is a text"),
        Text("Another text"),
        Text("third"),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("A asdjaks"),
        Text("B qohdaosd"),
        Text("C ashdjasd "),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("A asdjaks"),
        Text("B qohdaosd"),
        Text("C ashdjasd "),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: table_example]